# Chrome extension - Open dialog from javascript file (config in content_script)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem about Open dialog from javascript file (config in content_script). I use "chrome.windows.create" and have error: "Cannot read property 'create' of undefined". Have you any idea? 
Thanks you very much!
My source:

```js
**manifest.json**
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "short_name": "ABC",
  "description": "My tool",
  "permissions": [ "contentSettings", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" , "https://localhost/*", "https://localhost/*/*",  "contextMenus"],
  "homepage_url": "http://www.localhost/GMS",
  "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
  "manifest_version": 2,  
  "version": "1.0.4",
  "icons": {   
    "16": "img/icon-16.png",
    "48": "img/icon-48.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon-128.png",
    "default_popup": "background.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "css": [ "addon_tool.css" ],
    "js": [ "jquery.js", "config.js","myJs.js"]
  }]
}

**myJS.js**
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data:{UserName: 'name'},
            dataType: "json",
            url: "https://localhost/...",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('OK');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                try {
                    ***chrome.windows.create({ 'url': 'PopupForm.html', 'type': 'popup' }, function (window) {***
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e.message);
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
**PopupForm.html**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnSubmit" >Submit</button>
    <button id="btnCancel" >Close</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.windows.*` [can't be accessed in content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), you would need to move that logic to popup page or background page.

1. Rename `background.html` to `popup.html`. The previous name indicates that maybe you are confused about background page and popup page.
2. Add [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).
3. Move your `myJS` logic to background page.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. However, I must use content scripts. My problem is show dialog from content script (myJS.js).